# Is there any alternative of 'like' operators in sql - for searching data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need some help here, I am fetching data dependent upon the conditions

Here I am using like operators, where client may use search with any word thus I have the below logic but here retrieval time is too high (it's taking 4mins) to get the data which is too slow.

I did all indexing to table but still can't optimize the query.

select * from authors 
where (address like '% Walmart %' OR address like 'Walmart %' OR address like '% Walmart' OR address like '% Walmart.com %' OR address like 'Walmart.com %' OR address like '% Walmart.com' OR address like '% Walmarts %' OR address like 'Walmarts %' OR address like '% Walmarts' OR address like '% Walmarts.com %' OR address like 'Walmarts.com %' OR address like '% Walmarts.com')

-- Result is 1 Rows

if i follow this logic

select * from authors 
    where address like '%Walmart%'

-- Result is 44 rows - it is fetching all rows

But I need to get only that one row

Comment: Why do you allow for such types of searching, that is why it takes so long.  Look how many columns you are liking.

Comment: Do you find the redundant clauses improve performance?  Searching for `'%' + @word + '%'` should pretty much cover `@word`, `'% ' + @word` and `'@word + ' %'`.  And so on.

Comment: I have to check for only one column but because of that conditions its taking too long to retrieve the data.... if u know any better solution let me know... thanks in advance

Comment: yeah but logic was design in it manner only because i was using that pattern 4 times in a procedure

Comment: @HABO '%' + `@word` + '%' will cover every scenario, even the `@words`, `@wordcom`, and `@wordscom` because it will look for @word anywhere in the string.

Comment: @cadrell0 - That was my point.  Perhaps an optimization might use an index to get a match on `@word + '%'` and shortcut the rest, but it seems unlikely to help.

Comment: Using a single condition and a full text index is likely to be a significant improvement over 10 overlapping like clauses and an un-indexable query.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the only thing you need in the `where` clause, it should cover everything containing that word:

```
select * from authors
where address like '%' + @word + '%'
```

You are actually already doing this on the second line of the where clause:

```
or like '%'+@word+'%'
```

And that covers everything, making all other excessive. Removing those will probably speed it up a little:

```
declare @title varchar(20)

set @title = 'coll' set @title = LTRIM(rtrim(@title))

select * from authors
where address like '%'+@title+'%'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely indexing won't help. In many cases, when you use the Like statement, an index cannot be used. The type of searching you are allowing is highly inefficient. More than likely, this query will scan the address table. If the table has a sizeable number of rows in it, this will take a long time, as you're seeing.

You might be better off looking into full-text [searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: i did full-text searching on that column but still cann't able optimize it

Comment: What was your query after fulltext indexing? Did you use the contains keyword?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to get proper performance on text columns you will need to use full-text search.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard search like that won't be helped by an index, try looking at fulltext search instead

This will utilize an index, it will probably do a seek

```
address like @wordcom+' %
```

This will not utilize an index, it has to scan the whole index

```
address like '% '+@wordcom+' %'
```

Like mentioned above, use fulltext seach instead

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, all you need is

```
select * from authors where address like '%' + @word + '%'
```

This might not speed things up much, if the optimizer figured out what we are telling you.  (also the index won't help, and it is a good suggestion by others to use full-text searching).

In case you don't get why the query above is all you need, let's look at your query:

```
select * from authors
where address like @word or address like '% '+ @word
 or address like @word+' %' or address like '%'+@word+'%'
 or address like '% '+@word+' %' or address like @words
 or address like '% '+@words or address like @words+' %'
 or address like '%'+@words+'%' or address like '% '+@words+' %'
 or address like @wordcom or address like '% '+@wordcom
 or address like @wordcom+' %' or address like '%'+@wordcom+'%'
 or address like '% '+@wordcom+' %' or address like @wordscom
 or address like '% '+@wordscom or address like @wordscom+' %'
 or address like '% '+@wordscom+' %'
```

You do have a "like @word + '%'", so notice that if a record matches "like @word" it would also match "like @word + '%'".  So @word won't add any more results.  Because of the "or", the results will be the same wether @word is trying to match, or you just have results from @word+'%'.

Applying that logic, you query could be simplified to:

```
select * from authors
where address like @word+' %' or address like '%'+@word+'%'
 or address like @words+' %' or address like '%'+@words+'%'
 or address like @wordcom+' %' or address like '%'+@wordcom+'%'
 or address like @wordscom+' %' or address like '% '+@wordscom+' %'
```

Likewise, @word doesn't add anything that '%'+@word didn't already include, which thus simplifies the query to:

```
select * from authors
where address like '%'+@word+'%'
 or address like '%'+@words+'%'
 or address like '%'+@wordcom+'%'
 or address like '% '+@wordscom+' %'
```

Further, anything found by '%'+@word+'s%', '%'+@word+'.com%' or , '%'+@word+'s.com%' would be found by '%'+@word+'%'.

Comment: Thanks for your logic but in my senario if i am using this        AND (HD.address like '% Walmart %' OR HD.address like 'Walmart %' OR HD.address like '% Walmart' 
OR HD.address like '% Walmart.com %' OR HD.address like 'Walmart.com %' OR HD.address like '% Walmart.com' 
OR HD.address like '% Walmarts %' OR HD.address like 'Walmarts %' 
OR HD.address like '% Walmarts' OR HD.address like '% Walmarts.com %' OR HD.address like 'Walmarts.com %' 
OR HD.address like '% Walmarts.com')   -- Result is 1 rows  ,        where as if i follow -- AND HD.Title like '%Walmart%'
 -- result is 44 rows

Comment: In the comment above, you switched between a like on the address field and like on the Title field.  I am sure that AND (HD.address like '% Walmart %') will give the same results as the ORs of all those like statement.

Comment: If you can find a record which returns in one query but not the other (between like %@word@ and the OR version), let us know what the value of the field is.  Many of us are saying the query should have exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LIKE in your QUERY please use double %% to wrap the value to be filtered upon.
This is the best solution. Please vote if you like the solution.
For example in my case this was concatenated with the main query

```
filter_value = "'%%"+filter_value+"%%'"
```